# Fixed footer hiding content within scrollable content DIV

Tags: html, sass

I'm trying to create a layout that has a scrollable content area preventing the user from having to scroll the page, in this layout I have a fixed footer which seems to be problematic as my scrollable content is getting hidden behind this. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this? It looks like the scrollable card is actually using the full viewport height instead of the height available.

Adding `display:flex; flex-direction: column` to `.canvas-container` resolves this issue in chrome but not in safari so looking for something more consistent.

Comment: Your code is [tag:less] or [tag:scss], not CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using height 100% on the scroller content, you need it to be 100% minus the 42px of the footer so for this you can use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
.scroller__content {
    height: calc(100% - 42px);
}
```

I think this is the part of your code you need to change:

```css
.scroller {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    &__content {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        transform: translateZ(0);
        height: calc(100% - 42px);
    }
}
```

If you do not want to use experimental technology (although `calc` is pretty well supported), then you can use the following couple of lines in your `.scroller` class:

```css
.scroller {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    /* add the following 2 lines */
    padding-bottom: 42px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    &__content {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        transform: translateZ(0);
        height: calc(100% - 42px);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to get at the code of your original pen and have changed the styles as follows (mainly removing a lot of the height 100% and replacing them with flex-grow):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.app {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main-header {
    height: 52px;
    background: darken(#fff, 10);
}

.banner {
    height: 30px;
    background: darken(#fff, 20);
}

.canvas-container,
.canvas,
.region-cards,
.cards {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.card {
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    &__header {
        height: 40px;
        width:100%;
        background: darken(#fff, 50);
    }

    &__body {
        flex-grow: 1;
        position: relative;
    }

    &__content {
        position:absolute;
        top:0; 
        bottom:42px;
        left:0; 
        right:0; 
        overflow:auto;
        &--offset {

        }
    }
}

.main-footer {
    height: 42px;
    background: darken(#fff, 20);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZKRMv)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue - I still have the content stuck behind the footer

Comment: Do you need that html structure or can I simplify it?

Comment: Hey Pete unfortunately, I don't have a lot of scope right now to be able to simplify that structure :(

Comment: Ah right, I managed to get to the code in your pen and have fixed it - your problem was all those height 100% you put in everywhere.  I removed them and changed them all to flex so they will expand automatically - see edit above

Answer (score 1):

Add bottom padding to your div (with height of the footer).

```
.canvas-container {
  padding-bottom: 42px;
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 11 seconds :-P

Comment: this worked for me, after all this time. still a naive in css. :s

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add padding-bottom:40px to the canvas-container?

```
.canvas-container {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All are giving answers in pixels, but in responsive design this might cause problems.
You have a scroller class which has height 100% width 100%, change that to following:

```
.scroller {
    height: 96%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Works in all screen sizes.